# Clickhouse is using only one core after upgrading to version 22.3.2.1

Tags: clickhouse

I am using clickhouse version `22.3.2.1`. I want my clickhouse to utilise multiple cores.

This is my profile configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
<profiles>
    <default>
      <max_insert_threads>12</max_insert_threads>
      <max_threads>12</max_threads>
      <min_insert_block_size_bytes>536870912</min_insert_block_size_bytes>
      <min_insert_block_size_rows>1000000</min_insert_block_size_rows>
    </default>
</profiles>
```

I had the same configuration with version `v21.12` and it was working fine but after upgrading clickhouse to latest version. It is not using multiple cores.

this is my settings file

```
    min_compress_block_size 65536
    max_compress_block_size 1048576
    max_block_size  65505
    max_insert_block_size   1048545
    min_insert_block_size_rows  1000000
    min_insert_block_size_bytes 536870912
    min_insert_block_size_rows_for_materialized_views   0
    min_insert_block_size_bytes_for_materialized_views  0
    max_joined_block_size_rows  65505
    max_insert_threads  12
    max_final_threads   16
    max_threads 12
    max_read_buffer_size    1048576
    max_distributed_connections 1024
    max_query_size  262144
    interactive_delay   100000
    connect_timeout 10
    connect_timeout_with_failover_ms    50
    connect_timeout_with_failover_secure_ms 100
    receive_timeout 300
    send_timeout    300
    drain_timeout   3
    tcp_keep_alive_timeout  290
    hedged_connection_timeout_ms    100
    receive_data_timeout_ms 2000
    use_hedged_requests 1
    allow_changing_replica_until_first_data_packet  0
    queue_max_wait_ms   0
    connection_pool_max_wait_ms 0
    replace_running_query_max_wait_ms   5000
    kafka_max_wait_ms   5000
    rabbitmq_max_wait_ms    5000
    poll_interval   10
    idle_connection_timeout 3600
    distributed_connections_pool_size   1024
    connections_with_failover_max_tries 3
    s3_min_upload_part_size 16777216
    s3_upload_part_size_multiply_factor 2
    s3_upload_part_size_multiply_parts_count_threshold  1000
    s3_max_single_part_upload_size  33554432
    s3_max_single_read_retries  4
    s3_max_redirects    10
    s3_max_connections  1024
    s3_truncate_on_insert   0
    s3_create_new_file_on_insert    0
    hdfs_replication    0
    hdfs_truncate_on_insert 0
    hdfs_create_new_file_on_insert  0
    hsts_max_age    0
    extremes    0
    use_uncompressed_cache  0
    replace_running_query   0
    background_buffer_flush_schedule_pool_size  16
    background_pool_size    16
    background_merges_mutations_concurrency_ratio   2
    background_move_pool_size   8
    background_fetches_pool_size    8
    background_common_pool_size 8
    background_schedule_pool_size   128
    background_message_broker_schedule_pool_size    16
    background_distributed_schedule_pool_size   16
    max_replicated_fetches_network_bandwidth_for_server 0
    max_replicated_sends_network_bandwidth_for_server   0
    stream_like_engine_allow_direct_select  0
    distributed_directory_monitor_sleep_time_ms 100
    distributed_directory_monitor_max_sleep_time_ms 30000
    distributed_directory_monitor_batch_inserts 0
    distributed_directory_monitor_split_batch_on_failure    0
    optimize_move_to_prewhere   1
    optimize_move_to_prewhere_if_final  0
    replication_alter_partitions_sync   1
    replication_wait_for_inactive_replica_timeout   120
    load_balancing  random
    load_balancing_first_offset 0
    totals_mode after_having_exclusive
    totals_auto_threshold   0.5
    allow_suspicious_low_cardinality_types  0
    compile_expressions 1
    min_count_to_compile_expression 3
    compile_aggregate_expressions   1
    min_count_to_compile_aggregate_expression   3
    group_by_two_level_threshold    100000
    group_by_two_level_threshold_bytes  50000000
    distributed_aggregation_memory_efficient    1
    aggregation_memory_efficient_merge_threads  0
    enable_positional_arguments 0
    max_parallel_replicas   1
    parallel_replicas_count 0
    parallel_replica_offset 0
    allow_experimental_parallel_reading_from_replicas   0
    skip_unavailable_shards 0
    parallel_distributed_insert_select  0
    distributed_group_by_no_merge   0
    distributed_push_down_limit 1
    optimize_distributed_group_by_sharding_key  1
    optimize_skip_unused_shards_limit   1000
    optimize_skip_unused_shards 0
    optimize_skip_unused_shards_rewrite_in  1
    allow_nondeterministic_optimize_skip_unused_shards  0
    force_optimize_skip_unused_shards   0
    optimize_skip_unused_shards_nesting 0
    force_optimize_skip_unused_shards_nesting   0
    input_format_parallel_parsing   1
    min_chunk_bytes_for_parallel_parsing    10485760
    output_format_parallel_formatting   1
    merge_tree_min_rows_for_concurrent_read 163840
    merge_tree_min_bytes_for_concurrent_read    251658240
    merge_tree_min_rows_for_seek    0
    merge_tree_min_bytes_for_seek   0
    merge_tree_coarse_index_granularity 8
    merge_tree_max_rows_to_use_cache    1048576
    merge_tree_max_bytes_to_use_cache   2013265920
    do_not_merge_across_partitions_select_final 0
    mysql_max_rows_to_insert    65536
    optimize_min_equality_disjunction_chain_length  3
    min_bytes_to_use_direct_io  0
    min_bytes_to_use_mmap_io    0
    checksum_on_read    1
    force_index_by_date 0
    force_primary_key   0
    use_skip_indexes    1
    use_skip_indexes_if_final   0
    force_data_skipping_indices 
    max_streams_to_max_threads_ratio    1
    max_streams_multiplier_for_merge_tables 5
    network_compression_method  LZ4
    network_zstd_compression_level  1
    priority    0
    os_thread_priority  0
    log_queries 1
    log_formatted_queries   0
    log_queries_min_type    QUERY_START
    log_queries_min_query_duration_ms   0
    log_queries_cut_to_length   100000
    log_queries_probability 1
    distributed_product_mode    deny
    max_concurrent_queries_for_all_users    0
    max_concurrent_queries_for_user 0
    insert_deduplicate  1
    insert_quorum   0
    insert_quorum_timeout   600000
    insert_quorum_parallel  1
    select_sequential_consistency   0
    table_function_remote_max_addresses 1000
    read_backoff_min_latency_ms 1000
    read_backoff_max_throughput 1048576
    read_backoff_min_interval_between_events_ms 1000
    read_backoff_min_events 2
    read_backoff_min_concurrency    1
    memory_tracker_fault_probability    0
    enable_http_compression 0
    http_zlib_compression_level 3
    http_native_compression_disable_checksumming_on_decompress  0
    count_distinct_implementation   uniqExact
    add_http_cors_header    0
    max_http_get_redirects  0
    use_client_time_zone    0
    send_progress_in_http_headers   0
    http_headers_progress_interval_ms   100
    fsync_metadata  1
    join_use_nulls  0
    join_default_strictness ALL
    any_join_distinct_right_table_keys  0
    preferred_block_size_bytes  1000000
    max_replica_delay_for_distributed_queries   300
    fallback_to_stale_replicas_for_distributed_queries  1
    preferred_max_column_in_block_size_bytes    0
    insert_distributed_sync 0
    insert_distributed_timeout  0
    distributed_ddl_task_timeout    180
    stream_flush_interval_ms    7500
    stream_poll_timeout_ms  500
    sleep_in_send_tables_status_ms  0
    sleep_in_send_data_ms   0
    unknown_packet_in_send_data 0
    sleep_in_receive_cancel_ms  0
    insert_allow_materialized_columns   0
    http_connection_timeout 1
    http_send_timeout   180
    http_receive_timeout    180
    http_max_uri_size   1048576
    http_max_fields 1000000
    http_max_field_name_size    1048576
    http_max_field_value_size   1048576
    http_skip_not_found_url_for_globs   1
    optimize_throw_if_noop  0
    use_index_for_in_with_subqueries    1
    joined_subquery_requires_alias  1
    empty_result_for_aggregation_by_empty_set   0
    empty_result_for_aggregation_by_constant_keys_on_empty_set  1
    allow_distributed_ddl   1
    allow_suspicious_codecs 0
    allow_experimental_codecs   0
    query_profiler_real_time_period_ns  1000000000
    query_profiler_cpu_time_period_ns   1000000000
    metrics_perf_events_enabled 0
    metrics_perf_events_list    
    opentelemetry_start_trace_probability   0
    prefer_column_name_to_alias 0
    prefer_global_in_and_join   0
    max_rows_to_read    0
    max_bytes_to_read   0
    read_overflow_mode  throw
    max_rows_to_read_leaf   0
    max_bytes_to_read_leaf  0
    read_overflow_mode_leaf throw
    max_rows_to_group_by    0
    group_by_overflow_mode  throw
    max_bytes_before_external_group_by  0
    max_rows_to_sort    0
    max_bytes_to_sort   0
    sort_overflow_mode  throw
    max_bytes_before_external_sort  0
    max_bytes_before_remerge_sort   1000000000
    remerge_sort_lowered_memory_bytes_ratio 2
    max_result_rows 0
    max_result_bytes    0
    result_overflow_mode    throw
    max_execution_time  0
    timeout_overflow_mode   throw
    min_execution_speed 0
    max_execution_speed 0
    min_execution_speed_bytes   0
    max_execution_speed_bytes   0
    timeout_before_checking_execution_speed 10
    max_columns_to_read 0
    max_temporary_columns   0
    max_temporary_non_const_columns 0
    max_subquery_depth  100
    max_pipeline_depth  1000
    max_ast_depth   1000
    max_ast_elements    50000
    max_expanded_ast_elements   500000
    readonly    0
    max_rows_in_set 0
    max_bytes_in_set    0
    set_overflow_mode   throw
    max_rows_in_join    0
    max_bytes_in_join   0
    join_overflow_mode  throw
    join_any_take_last_row  0
    join_algorithm  hash
    default_max_bytes_in_join   1000000000
    partial_merge_join_left_table_buffer_bytes  0
    partial_merge_join_rows_in_right_blocks 65536
    join_on_disk_max_files_to_merge 64
    temporary_files_codec   LZ4
    max_rows_to_transfer    0
    max_bytes_to_transfer   0
    transfer_overflow_mode  throw
    max_rows_in_distinct    0
    max_bytes_in_distinct   0
    distinct_overflow_mode  throw
    max_memory_usage    28000000000
    max_guaranteed_memory_usage 0
    max_memory_usage_for_user   0
    max_guaranteed_memory_usage_for_user    0
    max_untracked_memory    4194304
    memory_profiler_step    4194304
    memory_profiler_sample_probability  0
    memory_usage_overcommit_max_wait_microseconds   0
    max_network_bandwidth   0
    max_network_bytes   0
    max_network_bandwidth_for_user  0
    max_network_bandwidth_for_all_users 0
    max_backup_threads  0
    log_profile_events  1
    log_query_settings  1
    log_query_threads   1
    log_query_views 1
    log_comment 
    send_logs_level fatal
    enable_optimize_predicate_expression    1
    enable_optimize_predicate_expression_to_final_subquery  1
    allow_push_predicate_when_subquery_contains_with    1
    low_cardinality_max_dictionary_size 8192
    low_cardinality_use_single_dictionary_for_part  0
    decimal_check_overflow  1
    prefer_localhost_replica    1
    max_fetch_partition_retries_count   5
    http_max_multipart_form_data_size   1073741824
    calculate_text_stack_trace  1
    allow_ddl   1
    parallel_view_processing    0
    enable_unaligned_array_join 0
    optimize_read_in_order  1
    optimize_aggregation_in_order   0
    aggregation_in_order_max_block_bytes    50000000
    read_in_order_two_level_merge_threshold 100
    low_cardinality_allow_in_native_format  1
    cancel_http_readonly_queries_on_client_close    0
    external_table_functions_use_nulls  1
    external_table_strict_query 0
    allow_hyperscan 1
    max_hyperscan_regexp_length 0
    max_hyperscan_regexp_total_length   0
    allow_simdjson  1
    allow_introspection_functions   0
    max_partitions_per_insert_block 100
    max_partitions_to_read  -1
    check_query_single_value_result 1
    allow_drop_detached 0
    postgresql_connection_pool_size 16
    postgresql_connection_pool_wait_timeout 5000
    glob_expansion_max_elements 1000
    odbc_bridge_connection_pool_size    16
    distributed_replica_error_half_life 60
    distributed_replica_error_cap   1000
    distributed_replica_max_ignored_errors  0
    allow_experimental_live_view    0
    live_view_heartbeat_interval    15
    max_live_view_insert_blocks_before_refresh  64
    allow_experimental_window_view  0
    window_view_clean_interval  5
    window_view_heartbeat_interval  15
    min_free_disk_space_for_temporary_data  0
    default_database_engine Atomic
    default_table_engine    None
    show_table_uuid_in_table_create_query_if_not_nil    0
    database_atomic_wait_for_drop_and_detach_synchronously  0
    enable_scalar_subquery_optimization 1
    optimize_trivial_count_query    1
    optimize_respect_aliases    1
    mutations_sync  0
    optimize_move_functions_out_of_any  0
    optimize_normalize_count_variants   1
    optimize_injective_functions_inside_uniq    1
    convert_query_to_cnf    0
    optimize_arithmetic_operations_in_aggregate_functions   1
    optimize_duplicate_order_by_and_distinct    1
    optimize_redundant_functions_in_order_by    1
    optimize_if_chain_to_multiif    0
    optimize_if_transform_strings_to_enum   0
    optimize_monotonous_functions_in_order_by   1
    optimize_functions_to_subcolumns    0
    optimize_using_constraints  0
    optimize_substitute_columns 0
    optimize_append_index   0
    normalize_function_names    1
    allow_experimental_alter_materialized_view_structure    0
    enable_early_constant_folding   1
    deduplicate_blocks_in_dependent_materialized_views  0
    use_compact_format_in_distributed_parts_names   1
    validate_polygons   1
    max_parser_depth    1000
    temporary_live_view_timeout 5
    periodic_live_view_refresh  60
    transform_null_in   0
    allow_nondeterministic_mutations    0
    lock_acquire_timeout    120
    materialize_ttl_after_modify    1
    function_implementation 
    allow_experimental_geo_types    0
    data_type_default_nullable  0
    cast_keep_nullable  0
    cast_ipv4_ipv6_default_on_conversion_error  0
    alter_partition_verbose_result  0
    allow_experimental_database_materialized_mysql  0
    allow_experimental_database_materialized_postgresql 0
    system_events_show_zero_values  0
    mysql_datatypes_support_level   
    optimize_trivial_insert_select  1
    allow_non_metadata_alters   1
    enable_global_with_statement    1
    aggregate_functions_null_for_empty  0
    optimize_syntax_fuse_functions  0
    optimize_fuse_sum_count_avg 0
    flatten_nested  1
    asterisk_include_materialized_columns   0
    asterisk_include_alias_columns  0
    optimize_skip_merged_partitions 0
    optimize_on_insert  1
    force_optimize_projection   0
    async_socket_for_remote 1
    insert_null_as_default  1
    describe_extend_object_types    0
    describe_include_subcolumns 0
    optimize_rewrite_sum_if_to_count_if 1
    insert_shard_id 0
    allow_experimental_query_deduplication  0
    engine_file_empty_if_not_exists 0
    engine_file_truncate_on_insert  0
    engine_file_allow_create_multiple_files 0
    allow_experimental_database_replicated  0
    database_replicated_initial_query_timeout_sec   300
    max_distributed_depth   5
    database_replicated_always_detach_permanently   0
    database_replicated_allow_only_replicated_engine    0
    distributed_ddl_output_mode throw
    distributed_ddl_entry_format_version    1
    external_storage_max_read_rows  0
    external_storage_max_read_bytes 0
    external_storage_connect_timeout_sec    10
    external_storage_rw_timeout_sec 300
    union_default_mode  
    optimize_aggregators_of_group_by_keys   1
    optimize_group_by_function_keys 1
    legacy_column_name_of_tuple_literal 0
    query_plan_enable_optimizations 1
    query_plan_max_optimizations_to_apply   10000
    query_plan_filter_push_down 1
    regexp_max_matches_per_row  1000
    limit   0
    offset  0
    function_range_max_elements_in_block    500000000
    short_circuit_function_evaluation   enable
    local_filesystem_read_method    pread
    remote_filesystem_read_method   threadpool
    local_filesystem_read_prefetch  0
    remote_filesystem_read_prefetch 1
    read_priority   0
    merge_tree_min_rows_for_concurrent_read_for_remote_filesystem   163840
    merge_tree_min_bytes_for_concurrent_read_for_remote_filesystem  251658240
    remote_read_min_bytes_for_seek  4194304
    async_insert_threads    16
    async_insert    0
    wait_for_async_insert   1
    wait_for_async_insert_timeout   120
    async_insert_max_data_size  100000
    async_insert_busy_timeout_ms    200
    async_insert_stale_timeout_ms   0
    remote_fs_read_max_backoff_ms   10000
    remote_fs_read_backoff_max_tries    5
    remote_fs_enable_cache  1
    remote_fs_cache_max_wait_sec    5
    http_max_tries  10
    http_retry_initial_backoff_ms   100
    http_retry_max_backoff_ms   10000
    force_remove_data_recursively_on_drop   0
    check_table_dependencies    1
    use_local_cache_for_remote_storage  1
    allow_unrestricted_reads_from_keeper    0
    allow_experimental_funnel_functions 0
    allow_experimental_nlp_functions    0
    allow_experimental_object_type  0
    insert_deduplication_token  
    max_memory_usage_for_all_queries    0
    multiple_joins_rewriter_version 0
    enable_debug_queries    0
    allow_experimental_database_atomic  1
    allow_experimental_bigint_types 1
    allow_experimental_window_functions 1
    handle_kafka_error_mode default
    database_replicated_ddl_output  1
    replication_alter_columns_timeout   60
    odbc_max_field_size 0
    allow_experimental_map_type 1
    merge_tree_clear_old_temporary_directories_interval_seconds 60
    merge_tree_clear_old_parts_interval_seconds 1
    partial_merge_join_optimizations    0
    max_alter_threads   \'auto(12)\'
    allow_experimental_projection_optimization  1
    format_csv_delimiter    ,
    format_csv_allow_single_quotes  1
    format_csv_allow_double_quotes  1
    output_format_csv_crlf_end_of_line  0
    input_format_csv_enum_as_number 0
    input_format_csv_arrays_as_nested_csv   0
    input_format_skip_unknown_fields    0
    input_format_with_names_use_header  1
    input_format_with_types_use_header  1
    input_format_import_nested_json 0
    input_format_defaults_for_omitted_fields    1
    input_format_csv_empty_as_default   1
    input_format_tsv_empty_as_default   0
    input_format_tsv_enum_as_number 0
    input_format_null_as_default    1
    input_format_use_lowercase_column_name  0
    input_format_arrow_import_nested    0
    input_format_orc_import_nested  0
    input_format_orc_row_batch_size 100000
    input_format_parquet_import_nested  0
    input_format_allow_seeks    1
    input_format_orc_allow_missing_columns  0
    input_format_parquet_allow_missing_columns  0
    input_format_arrow_allow_missing_columns    0
    input_format_hive_text_fields_delimiter 
    input_format_hive_text_collection_items_delimiter   
    input_format_hive_text_map_keys_delimiter   
    input_format_msgpack_number_of_columns  0
    output_format_msgpack_uuid_representation   ext
    input_format_max_rows_to_read_for_schema_inference  100
    date_time_input_format  basic
    date_time_output_format simple
    bool_true_representation    true
    bool_false_representation   false
    input_format_values_interpret_expressions   1
    input_format_values_deduce_templates_of_expressions 1
    input_format_values_accurate_types_of_literals  1
    input_format_avro_allow_missing_fields  0
    format_avro_schema_registry_url 
    output_format_json_quote_64bit_integers 1
    output_format_json_quote_denormals  0
    output_format_json_escape_forward_slashes   1
    output_format_json_named_tuples_as_objects  0
    output_format_json_array_of_rows    0
    output_format_pretty_max_rows   10000
    output_format_pretty_max_column_pad_width   250
    output_format_pretty_max_value_width    10000
    output_format_pretty_color  1
    output_format_pretty_grid_charset   UTF-8
    output_format_parquet_row_group_size    1000000
    output_format_avro_codec    
    output_format_avro_sync_interval    16384
    output_format_avro_string_column_pattern    
    output_format_avro_rows_in_file 1
    output_format_tsv_crlf_end_of_line  0
    format_csv_null_representation  \\N
    format_tsv_null_representation  \\N
    output_format_decimal_trailing_zeros    0
    input_format_allow_errors_num   0
    input_format_allow_errors_ratio 0
    format_schema   
    format_template_resultset   
    format_template_row 
    format_template_rows_between_delimiter  \n
    format_custom_escaping_rule Escaped
    format_custom_field_delimiter   \t
    format_custom_row_before_delimiter  
    format_custom_row_after_delimiter   \n
    format_custom_row_between_delimiter 
    format_custom_result_before_delimiter   
    format_custom_result_after_delimiter    
    format_regexp   
    format_regexp_escaping_rule Raw
    format_regexp_skip_unmatched    0
    output_format_enable_streaming  0
    output_format_write_statistics  1
    output_format_pretty_row_numbers    0
    insert_distributed_one_random_shard 0
    cross_to_inner_join_rewrite 1
    output_format_arrow_low_cardinality_as_dictionary   0
    format_capn_proto_enum_comparising_mode by_values
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look like you run clickhouse inside docker,
issue related with cgroups limits calculation
And fixed on next 22.3.x

Look details
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/35815

Comment: Hi @Slach thanks for the reply but I am using clickhouse inside a VM without docker. It was working fine before upgradation

Comment: What kind of VM do you use? Virtualbox? QEMU? Windows WSL? VMWare?

Which Host OS?

Comment: I am using `VMWare` with `CentOS Linux version 8`

Comment: I noticed one more thing that this is happening only with insert select queries. Only select is working fine @Slach

Comment: Which input format do you use when execute INSERT statement?

Comment: Default format. This is my query `insert into table main_table( col0, col1, col2, col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8) with mongo_data as (select identity, argMax(id, date) as id FROM mongo_table group by identity) select tmp.* from tmp_table tmp left join mongo_data mongo on mongo.identity = tmp.col1 SETTINGS join_use_nulls = 1` @Slach

Comment: look to max_insert_threads for `insert ... select`
and check your 

EXPLAIN PIPELINE with mongo_data as (select identity, argMax(id, date) as id FROM mongo_table group by identity) select tmp.* from tmp_table tmp left join mongo_data mongo on mongo.identity = tmp.col1 SETTINGS join_use_nulls = 1

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-max-insert-threads

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243685/discussion-between-zunnurain-badar-and-slach).

Answer (score 0):

After your comments

look like you need to increase `max_insert_threads` for INSERT ... SELECT ...

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-max-insert-threads

and check EXPLAIN for SELECT
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/explain/

Comment: My value for  `max_insert_threads`  is already  `12`. And when i run select query it takes almost 3,4 mins and use all of the cores

Comment: did you try check EXPLAIN INSERT ... SELECT and compare with EXPLAIN SELECT ?

Comment: check settings for you `INSERT ... SELECT` query in system.query_log